# USB mouse switched off when laptop on battery and temperature rises

Tags: laptop, usb, mouse, battery, temperature

My USB mouse is disabled when my laptop is running on battery power
and the CPU or GPU temperature rises. 
It enables the mouse when the temperature is down
or when I plug in the laptop power cable.

I've tried all the solutions, like:

> Unselect 'Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power' on Device Manager

or

> Disable 'USB selective suspend setting' on Power Options

but it still disabling the mouse USB port on battery as described above.